# Get and Set values form spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-sdk-2.3

I'm looking for to get and set values form spinner loades from database but i don't find it.

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllCadenesAsList();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

The cursor returns _id and Name and the spinner load correctly (it seems..)

Now when I try to get de selected valued in onItemSelected, I the id and the position is the same, and is not a id of cursor, it is the posicion in de spinner.

How can I get de ID of selected value?
How can I set the value of spinner.

I need and I know the id of database, not the id/position of spinner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are getting Name from Spinner then make query to database again using Where clause like `SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE Name =spinnerselectedtext`

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a real database `_id` on `onItemSelected` of the spinner because you hooked the spinner up to an `ArrayAdapter`. This sort of adapter hookup is not in any way connected to your database but only the `List<String>` or other collection you passed into it. To get what you want, you need to set the spinner's adapter to a `CursorAdapter` instead.